# Appcelerator Alloy: remove a window from memory after opening another

Tags: android, titanium-alloy

I'm writing an Android app using Titanium Alloy.

This app has multiple `View` files and it is based on a lot of Windows elements.

*Just for making a simple example, think about this:*

I have two `View` files: `index.xml` (with its Controller `index.js`) and `win02.xml` (with its Controller `win02.js`). `index.xml` has a Button. I want to open `win02` from index by pressing its Button and I want everything about `index` to be removed from memory so I avoid possible memory leaks.

Inside `index.js`, I put this code:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   Alloy.createController('win02').getView().open();     
});
```

And, in doing so, I am able to open the `win02` Window. But how can I totally remove index? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a window you can call `close()` so `$.index.close();` just after you create `win02`, that should do the trick.